# How to relate a version of @types package to the versions of the associated JS package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I am working on a nodejs project with typescript 2.2 that is using node 6.3.1 and I want to migrate from using typings to using @types. By doing so I ran into a set of questions related to whether there is a relationship between the version of the @types file and the corresponding npm package.

If I use jasmine as an example, the existing versions of the types definitions are

```
npm show @types/jasmine@* version
@types/jasmine@1.3.0 '1.3.0'
@types/jasmine@1.3.1 '1.3.1'
@types/jasmine@1.3.2 '1.3.2'
@types/jasmine@2.2.29 '2.2.29'
@types/jasmine@2.2.30 '2.2.30'
@types/jasmine@2.2.31 '2.2.31'
@types/jasmine@2.2.32 '2.2.32'
@types/jasmine@2.2.33 '2.2.33'
@types/jasmine@2.2.34 '2.2.34'
@types/jasmine@2.5.35 '2.5.35'
@types/jasmine@2.5.36 '2.5.36'
@types/jasmine@2.5.37 '2.5.37'
@types/jasmine@2.5.38 '2.5.38'
@types/jasmine@2.5.39 '2.5.39'
@types/jasmine@2.5.40 '2.5.40'
@types/jasmine@2.5.41 '2.5.41'
@types/jasmine@2.5.42 '2.5.42'
@types/jasmine@2.5.43 '2.5.43'
@types/jasmine@2.5.44 '2.5.44'
@types/jasmine@2.5.45 '2.5.45'
@types/jasmine@2.5.46 '2.5.46'
```

But if I examine the versions of the jasmine packages I have;

```
npm show jasmine@* version
jasmine@2.0.1 '2.0.1'
jasmine@2.1.0 '2.1.0'
jasmine@2.1.1 '2.1.1'
jasmine@2.2.0 '2.2.0'
jasmine@2.2.1 '2.2.1'
jasmine@2.3.0 '2.3.0'
jasmine@2.3.1 '2.3.1'
jasmine@2.3.2 '2.3.2'
jasmine@2.4.0 '2.4.0'
jasmine@2.4.1 '2.4.1'
jasmine@2.5.0 '2.5.0'
jasmine@2.5.1 '2.5.1'
jasmine@2.5.2 '2.5.2'
jasmine@2.5.3 '2.5.3'
```

Let’s say I am using version 2.4.0 of jasmine, which version of @types/jasmine should I pick? Because even if I use the latest of both, 2.5.46 does not match with 2.5.3.

Another example would be node itself, there are basically 6.0 or 7.0 versions in @types, and typings has only the ones shown below, being 6.0 reported as obsolete. So, what version of node are those typings actually tied to?

```
typings view dt~node --versions
TAG                  VERSION DESCRIPTION COMPILER LOCATION
                          UPDATED
7.0.0+20170322231424 7.0.0                        github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/index.d.ts#a4a912a0cd1849fa7df0e5d909c8625fba04e49d 2017-03-22T23:14:24.000Z
6.0.0+20161121110008 6.0.0                        github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts#fb7fbd28b477f5e239467e69397ed020d92817e7  2016-11-21T11:00:08.000Z
```

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The major and minor versions of the DefinitelyTyped packages are supposed to correspond to the major and minor versions of the package they are types for. The patch version increments whenever the .d.ts file changes for other reasons. Because the minor version shouldn't represent breaking changes, in theory, you can use the highest `2.x.y` definition file available for a `2.a.b.c` library.

But now the caveats begin.

- The header in the definition file may not have changed at the right time
- Library authors do not necessarily follow semver*
- The definition file may not be 100% correct at any given point, in either direction (i.e. listing a 2.6 feature under a 2.5 version, or failing to list a 2.4 in function in the 2.5 file)

`*` In fact, no one does

---

A detailed explanation can be found in official docs FAQ: 
[How do Definitely Typed package versions relate to versions of the corresponding library?](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-definitely-typed-package-versions-relate-to-versions-of-the-corresponding-library)

Comment: Ryan where does Your knowledge comes from? Could You please provide links to read? I struggle to match some libraries and their @types. It seems a big problem to me..

Comment: My knowledge comes from me designing and implementing @types

Comment: LOL :) ok, is there any map what version of @ types use for eg jQuery 1.4? Are there any guides for any library/framework? I am looking aspecialy for AngularJS @ types specific version that exactly reflect angular version I am using. Same with ui-router (angular-ui-router)

Comment: I see that this conversation has not been updated in a year now, I just asked a similar question and marked my question as a duplicate of this question.  Are there any updates regarding your response @RyanCavanaugh ?  Or is this still a hit/miss depending on the types package?

Comment: "Because the minor version shouldn't represent breaking changes, in theory, you can use the highest" ... That's not exactly true because new types could include _new_ functions/etc. which are non-breaking changes. You're types should match the version installed. Unfortunate that they're using the 3rd digit as a type change indicator rather than mapping directly to the exact version the type is for and using a `-type.x` or similar indicator to track definition tweaks.