# How does @types figure out which version of Express.js to use?

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-typings

I just started using **TypeScript**. 
I'm trying to install **Express.js**. I've figured out that I can install the types of **Express.js** by doing

```
npm install @types/express
```

My question is how does **TypeScript** know what version of **Express.js** I have? Does it automatically look at my `package.json` file and figure out the right version or are there flags I have to add to the command to specify the version of **Express.js** I am using?

Comment: title says node, but I mean expressjs

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071705/how-to-relate-a-version-of-types-to-the-versions-of-the-associated-package-in-n

Comment: thanks! does that mean the versions get matched automatically or do I have to manually specify the versions when I install the types.

Comment: There is no automatic matching, the versions should be specified manually, and in general there is no guarantee that there is compatible version of typings for any particular version of the library.