# How to know which version of types package to use

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I know that some npm packages don’t include types and due to that community creates @types/packagename to supply types. Since both are packages how does one know which version of types package to use with the chosen version of library package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to relate a version of @types package to the versions of the associated JS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071705/how-to-relate-a-version-of-types-package-to-the-versions-of-the-associated-js-p)

Answer (score 10):

The major and minor version numbers of the `@types/packagename` package will match the major and minor version numbers of the `packagename` package. The patch numbers do not match: the types package will start with the patch number `0` and this will be incremented for every update to the types package for the same major/minor versions of the library.

For example, if you are using `packagename@1.2.3`, you would install the latest `@types/packagename@1.2.x`.

You can read more on [‘How do Definitely Typed package versions relate to versions of the corresponding library?’ on the DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-definitely-typed-package-versions-relate-to-versions-of-the-corresponding-library) ([permalink](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/679571bbfcc8f0007fecfb96769d48fee1451059/README.md#how-do-definitely-typed-package-versions-relate-to-versions-of-the-corresponding-library)), which is where the source of the `@types` packages are located.