# Determine compatible versions between @types/<package> and <package>

Tags: typescript, npm, version

Say I have installed a package `some-package` from the npm registry, how can i look up what version i should install from `@types/some-package` assuming it also exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know which version of types package to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741594/how-to-know-which-version-of-types-package-to-use)